# iText7 PdfReaded loading IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext7

I am trying to use the iText7 library but for some reason, I cannot split pages into the list of strings.

Instead, I am getting a list of pages like this:
1,1+2,1+2+3,1+2+3+4

```html
 public List<string> PdfPages;
        private ITextExtractionStrategy _Strategy;
        public PdfExtractor(IFormFile pdf, ITextExtractionStrategy? strategy = default)
        {
            this._Strategy = strategy ?? new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            PdfPages = new List<string>();
            ExtractTextFromPages(pdf);
        }
        private void ExtractTextFromPages(IFormFile pdf)
        {
            using (var stream = pdf.OpenReadStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new PdfReader(stream))
                {
                    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);

                    for (int index = 1; index < pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); index++)
                    {
                        string PdfPageToText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(index), _Strategy);
                        PdfPages.Add(PdfPageToText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know how to correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as @mkl mentioned in the comment below, that I did not create a new ITextExtractionStrategy object for each page, and when I did that everything works like a charm without the need to save files anywhere.

```
  using (var stream = pdf.OpenReadStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader(stream))
            {
                PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);

                for (int index = 1; index < pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); index++)
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                    string PdfPageToText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(index), strategy);
                    PdfPages.Add(PdfPageToText);
                }
                pdfDoc.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The relevant change in your fix is that you now create a new `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` instance for each page while you originally re-used the same instance. The other changes are irrelevant.

Comment: @mkl You were right, I have changed my code to generate a new ITextExtractionStrategy for each page and it works! Thank you!